# Need clarification on Trigger.new

Tags: apex

I have `contact object` and one of its field is `Account` which is in lookup relationship.

In one of contact trigger i have used

```
for(Contact con: Trigger.New)
{
       //code
}
```

If I try to print `con.Account.name` it is showing null even though account has name. what would be the cause.

Actually can we access like `con.Account.name`??

Regards,
Gayathri

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No in `trigger.New` you can't access parent object fields directly. You need to query them to access..

for example.

```
Set<Id> accId = new Set<Id>();
for(Contact con: Trigger.New)
{
       accId.add(con.accountId);
}
List<Account> accList = [select id, name from account WHERE Id IN: accId ]; //access name from this list
```

Comment: I have tried that way as well I have queried and put that in map but it is not working

Comment: @user27888 what is not working her? share your updated code.

Comment: Based on Accountname and contact field's condition I have sending actionid to sap. Actionid not flowing to SAP if I add extra condition of Account name from map

Comment: @user27888 can you share your update code.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can do the following:

```
List<Contact> lst_contacts = 
    [SELECT Id, Name, Account.Name
    FROM Contact
    WHERE Id IN :Trigger.new];

// Now access account field directly from the contacts
For (Contact myContact : lst_contacts) {
    System.debug('Account Name = ' + myContact.Account.Name);
}
```

But I personally prefer the first approach given by Tushar. In my experience, it is better to use collections rather than querying parent objects. But it is an option.